# C# asp.net web api returning List<BsonDocument> how to keep Mongodb serializer from adding Name Value fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, mongodb

Web api function that is generating a List that the web api is returning via Telerik DataSourceResult

```
List<BsonDocument> objs = _mongoStore.GetData(id, newTime);
DataSourceResult result = objs.ToDataSourceResult(request);
return Json(result);
```

When I look in a debugger at the objs variable I see it represented in the following way; which is how we want the Json returned web api data:

```
{ "Computer" : "Computer1", "OSVersion" : "Windows" }
```

However when the Json() function serializes the objs object it is adding Name Value fields such as the following:

```
[[{"Name":"Computer","Value":"Computer1"},{"Name":"OSVersion","Value":"Windows"}]]
```

This expansion to Name, Value, fields is breaking future Json parsing APIs we use. How do we serialize this so that it just uses the actual values for Name and Value vs. it adding a specific Name and Value field? I.E. We want the returned Json to resemble like what the debugger is seeing:

```
{ "Computer" : "Computer1", "OSVersion" : "Windows" }
```

I know that one could do something like:

```
string rawjson = objs.ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings {OutputMode = JsonOutput.Strict});
```

But not sure how one would use something like that globally so if you were to be returning a Telerik DataSourceResult such as:

```
DataSourceResult result = objs.ToDataSourceResult(request);
return Json(Result);
```

Would cause the serialization that happens to return proper Json without the Name Value added fields.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can actually just take the result DataSourceResult object and perform Mongo .ToJson against it then return the web api as raw json string content.

So fixed up it would be something like

```
List<BsonDocument> objs = _mongoStore.GetData(id, newTime);
DataSourceResult result = objs.ToDataSourceResult(request);
var finalResult=result.ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict });
return Content(finalResult);
```

Not sure if there is a better way but this seems to work. If someone else knows a better way happy to change that to the Answer.